# Windows ipconfig returns wrong external IP address

Tags: windows, router, terminal, ip

I have recently changed my external IP address but for some reason, **ipconfig** is still returning the old IP address:

[image]

My old external IP address starts with `93`. If I access my router or [whatismyip.net](https://www.whatismyip.net/) it returns another ip address.

Running `ipconfig /release` and `ipconfig /renew` didn't work.

Those commands might be more appropriate to change the local IP address but even that one remained unchanged.

This is a problem because I am trying to run a file (related to an MMORPG game) where I am supposed to specify the external IP address and it only works with my old external IP address.

What else should I try?

Comment: Local IPs are determined by your router which is always in charge and may or may not actually release and renew.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you for clarifying that @ChanganAuto. Still not sure why is windows displaying the wrong external ip address.

Comment: The external IP is defined by your ISP. If static it won't change; if dynamic as in most SOHO service plans then it may. If possible then it's in the router settings, not from any WiFi or Ethernet connected computer in the local network. And, of course, it may not be possible at all, it depends on the ISP.

Comment: Where is ipconfig displaying it, exactly?

Comment: @user1686 I've updated the post with a screenshot. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

`ipconfig` is displaying your local IP, not your public external IP,
which it has no way of knowing. Your computer has no direct connection
to the internet, so has to go through the router for that.

In addition, your local IP is allocated by your router.
Most routers try to allocate the same IP to the same computer,
even when the DHCP lease is renewed.

Only the router knows your public external IP. You can find it by entering
its webpage, or more simply via sites such as
[WhatlsMylP.net](https://www.whatismyip.net/).

Comment: If only the router knows my public external IP, why does the ipconfig returns my old public external IP? (please see the screenshot I've added to the post)

Comment: Let's try to understand it : Run *Settings > Network & Internet > Status > Change adapter options*, right-click Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi, select Properties, click Internet Protocol version 4 (TCP/IPv4, click Properties. Add to your post the screenshot of the General tab. Add also a screenshot of the dialog for the Advanced... button. My guess is that you or someone used this button to add an IP address.

Comment: To get rid of the dummy `93...` address, try `ipconfig /release` and reboot. If that didn't help, try `netsh interface ipv4 delete address "Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi" addr=93...`

Comment: An adapter absolutely can have two different IPv4 addresses (or three, or four...) – if it couldn't, the netsh command you're suggesting wouldn't exist, etc. It does sound that the external address is misplaced here, though, but on Windows servers such a mix wouldn't be unusual at all.

Comment: @soltex: This can also be the result of some misguided software that added a previous external IP address to your adapter for some unknown reason. If you manage to delete as described above this address, but this happens again, you will need to locate this product.

Comment: @harrymc As you said, I went to the TCP/IP advanced options and the old external IP address was there with a 255.0.0.0 mask. I've changed that IP address to the new one, and now `ipconfig` is displaying the correct external IP address (and the MMORPG server is also working). Thank you! :)